# Http 404 when calling PUT on Lift with json body

Tags: scala, rest, lift

I'm trying to use Lift to do a Rest service, put I'm having problem when I try to pass a json body.

Model:

```
case class TestData(substore:String) {}

object TestData {  
  private implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats

  implicit def toJson(item: TestData): JValue = Extraction.decompose(item)

  def apply(in: JValue): Box[TestData] = Helpers.tryo{in.extract[TestData]}

  def unapply(in: Any): Option[TestData] = in match {
    case i: TestData => Some(TestData(i.substore)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Rest:

```
object RestExample extends RestHelper {
  serve {
    case "api" :: "user" :: AsLong(id) :: Nil JsonGet _ => JInt(id)
    case "api" :: "test2" :: Nil JsonPut _ => TestData("testeee"): JValue
    case "api" :: "test" :: Nil JsonPut TestData(testData) -> _ => testData : JValue
  }
}
```

The simple put test works:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT http://localhost:8080/api/test2
```

But i can't get the test with a json body working:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"substore":"abs"}' http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

in this case I always receive:

```
<html> <body>The Requested URL /api/test was not found on this server</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like a pattern-matching problem.

Would replacing `TestData(testData)` with `JObject(JField("substore", JString(substore)))` solve your problem? You'll have `substore: String` in the scope with such pattern matching.

Also, in the `TestData` object, why do you use `Any` instead of `JValue`? And where would it's `apply` method called, I don't see any usages (`TestData` isn't called with a `JValue` anywhere).

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing as here: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-5.4.html  , I would like to have a TestData instance instead of using `JObject(JField("substore", JString(substore)))` like on this page is done to Item. Thanks!

Comment: Good, clear. Try to copy the `unapply` method from here for a start?: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-5.2.html  (As you see, there are two methods `unapply` there.)

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `def unapply(in: JValue): Option[BCashData] = apply(in)`, now everything works fine!